# SQL Server Missing Backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-backups

I'm trying to get a list of missing full backups, but I need this list to show me which user performed the latest backup. The problem is, I don't know how to filter that, since what I'm querying is returning all the last backups for each user.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName,
    d.[name] AS DatabaseName,
    b.user_name as UserName,
    'Backups Not Performed Recently' AS Finding,
    'Last backed up: ' + COALESCE(CAST(MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(25)),'never') AS Details
FROM    
    master.sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.backupset b ON d.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.database_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                         AND b.type = 'D'
                         AND b.server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') /*Backupset ran on current server */
WHERE   
    d.database_id <> 2  /* Bonus points if you know what that means */
    AND d.state NOT IN(1, 6, 10) /* Not currently offline or restoring, like log shipping databases */
    AND d.is_in_standby = 0 /* Not a log shipping target database */
    AND d.source_database_id IS NULL /* Excludes database snapshots */
GROUP BY 
    d.name, b.user_name
HAVING  
    MAX(b.backup_finish_date) <= DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
    OR MAX(b.backup_finish_date) IS NULL
```

Returns:

```
ServerName  DatabaseName    UserName    Finding Details
ServerA     DatabaseA       Userxyz     Backups Not Performed Recently  Last backed up: Nov 30 2016  2:45PM
ServerA     DatabaseA       Userabc     Backups Not Performed Recently  Last backed up: Nov 24 2016 12:36PM
ServerA     DatabaseA       Userdef     Backups Not Performed Recently  Last backed up: Feb  5 2017  1:26AM
```

When I just need it to return the id and results from the latest date. Desired result would look like this:

```
ServerName  DatabaseName    UserName    Finding Details
ServerA     DatabaseA       Userxyz     Backups Not Performed Recently  Last backed up: Feb  5 2017  1:26AM
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use row number here to choose the most recent backup entry for each database:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName,
           d.[name] AS DatabaseName,
           b.user_name as UserName,
           'Backups Not Performed Recently' AS Finding,
           'Last backed up: ' + COALESCE(CAST(MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(25)),'never') AS Details,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.[name] ORDER BY MAX(b.backup_finish_date) DESC) rn
    FROM master.sys.databases d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b
        ON d.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.database_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND
           b.type = 'D' AND
           b.server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
    WHERE d.database_id <> 2 AND
          d.state NOT IN(1, 6, 10) AND
          d.is_in_standby = 0 AND
          d.source_database_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY d.name,
             b.user_name
    HAVING MAX(b.backup_finish_date) <= DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) OR
           MAX(b.backup_finish_date) IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM cte t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: your solution is interesting, but I'm still facing issues on servers that the query should return nothing

Comment: @carolcastelli Then perhaps you should update your question with data which reflects the actual problem you are facing.  My query satisfies the test data you showed us.